# get selectedValue of dropdownlist from code behind

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

On an aspx page I have a dropdownlist and a button.

I select a value from the dropdownlist and click the button.

In the button event handler I have the statment: DropDownList1.SelectedValue;

This value is showing up as the first item in the list regardless of what item is actually selected.

Same result with .SelectedItem.Value and .Text

Why? And how do I get the item actually selected?

Comment: Do you rebind your Dropdown on every postback to the Datasource? Or do you have the same value for every item?

Comment: ? whats the question here? its working as it should...

Comment: @user287745 - clearly i'm having an issue or I would not have posted. It may be working as it should, but I'm asking how to make it work like I want to. Give me the item selected not the first item in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i create an answer from my comment.

Do you rebind your Dropdown on every postback to the Datasource or do you have the [same value](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/105329/dropdownlist-selecteditem-is-incorrect-when-dropdownlist-contains-multiple-items-with-the-same-value-even-if-they-have-different-text) for every item?

Always check for Page.IsPostback when you bind controls to a Datasource.

Comment: the button is actually a remove button. So the list has say two items. I selected the second and click the remove button. The event handler is supposed to get the selected value and remove it and then rebind. However I can't do that because i'm getting the first item in the list not the selected one.

Comment: You didn't even have answered one of my two questions that could cause a wrong selected item. Btw, what is theSelectedIndex of the Dropdown? Please show us some code of your databinding and event handler.

Comment: Sorry. I was researching the other two answers. didn't want to speculate. I was binding in the pageload which is unnecessary because i do the bind both when the add button is clicked and when the remove button is clicked. I removed these binds from my page load altogether and it works. Thanks! your mention of the binding on postback lead me to the answer.